# ES query for one field exists, or if another has a certain value

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-7

I'm working on a dataset in Elasticsearch 7.6 where one field (published_at) is conditionally set. We're migrating to a new field (published) which will either be True or False, but I need to support backwards compatibility and can't backfill the dataset for all documents. Where i've landed is needing a query to check if the `published_at` field exists, or if `published` is set to True.

Here's where i've gotten so far, but this is instead giving me all documents:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {"exists": {"field": "published_at"}},
        {
          "terms": {
            "published": [
              "true"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show one document that has neither the `published_at` field nor `published: true`?

Comment: You should use 'must' instead of 'should'